# Retrieve data of a collection base on users session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Is it appropriate that my collections have a key call session so that I can identify from whom this data belongs to? For example, I have few sets of data that store books. How to identify in nosql DB(MongoDB) that a set of data belongs to which user? I know in mysql we simply design the table using Foreign Key, but how can I do it in nosql?

What I can think of is I will have these data :

```
{
bookId:1,
  bookName: "soemthing",
    userId:1
}

{
  another_collection_key:1,
  another_value: "soemthing",
   userId:1
}
```

where every set of data will have userId, correct?

Comment: we need to understand difference between referential integrity rules Vs foreign key.Since, there is no concept of Foreign key in NOsql DB's

Comment: @Mani so I have to put userid into any collection?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/database-references/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a user collection and a book collection. In each book collection add a list of type 'user'. Sample collections given below -

```
User{id,name}
Book{id,name,list<user>}
```

This way each book can store all the users who have that book. 
The other way is to create 3 collections - books, users and a link collection for linking book and user. 
Sample collections given below -

```
User { id,name }
Books { id,name }
Lnk_User_Book { User_Id,Book_Id }.
```